# Field 'album_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to create a photo album using laravel version 8.9.0
I have created an album, when I click on an album I will go to the gallery view, when I upload a photo an error occurs like this

General error: 1364 Field 'album_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `galeris` (`deskripsi`, `user_id`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asa, 1, 1604133200.png, 2020-10-31 08:33:20, 2020-10-31 08:33:20))

**create_galeris_table.php**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('galeris', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('album_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('image');
            $table->text('deskripsi');
            $table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums')->onDelete('CASCADE')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**GaleriController.php**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'deskripsi' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2000',
        ]);

        $galeri = New Galeri;
        $galeri->deskripsi = $request->deskripsi;
        $galeri->user_id = auth()->id();

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $fileName = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = public_path('images/galeri');
            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            $galeri->image = $fileName;
        }

        $galeri->save();
        return back()->with(['success' => 'Data Berhasil Disimpan!']);
    }
```

**galeri.blade.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="uploadImage" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="{{route('galeri.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" style="padding-top: 3px;">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="deskripsi" class="form-control" placeholder="Deskripsi"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Save</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the error says, you need to insert `album_id` while creating new instance

Comment: on your blade do you have the `id` of `album` ??

Comment: i don't have it

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: As per your migration table, your gallery item is belongsTo a album, so you need to pass the album_id while insert new record, or make it nullable (nullable is not a good idea as per your migration)

Comment: how can i insert new record?

Answer (score 1):

Because in `create_galeris_table.php` migration file `album_id` field is not `nullable` or has a default value and in your `GaleriController.php` you are not inserting a value for `album_id`

So you could make `album_id` `nullable` in your migration file

```
$table->integer('album_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Or insert a value for `album_id` while creating a new gallery record, so in  `store` method you will add

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $request->validate([
            'deskripsi' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2000',
        ]);

        $galeri = New Galeri;
        $galeri->deskripsi = $request->deskripsi;
        $galeri->user_id = auth()->id();

        $album = Album::find('some-id'); // this id of the album you want to add to this gallery
        $galeri->album_id = $album->id; 

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $fileName = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = public_path('images/galeri');
            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            $galeri->image = $fileName;
        }

        $galeri->save();
        return back()->with(['success' => 'Data Berhasil Disimpan!']);
}
```

Comment: how can i insert a value for album_id when creating a new gallery record?

Comment: You have two ways either you pass your `album` from your view to the `store` method in your controller `store(Request $request, Ablum $album)` or fetch album details in `store` method like `$album = Album::find('some-id')` then you will do `$galeri->album_id = $album->id;`

Comment: why Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Album] does not exist.?

Comment: Yes because you need to import it `use App\Album;` or `$album = \App\Album::find('some-id'); `

Comment: I have imported use\Models\Album but why Trying to get property 'id' of non-object?